# Python pivot_table ignore NaN values from an excel table but my organization would like to use the blank field for adjustments

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pivot-table, nan

I have a excel table that has blank fields including some names etc.
When creating a pivot_table in Python, the function ignores these blank fields and does not count them.

so when a pivot_table index is done using names, the blank are NaN values and are ignored. But the accountant use these blank fields to make adjustment.